# Minify ceylon-sdk and ceylon-language when compiling to javascript

Tags: ceylon

For an in-browser application written in ceylon-js it would be desirable to reduce the size of the ceylon.language-1.2.0.js file to only that what is actually needed.

This question was answered already.

[How to use ceylon js (also with google closure compiler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119265/how-to-use-ceylon-js-also-with-google-closure-compiler)

But the given solution involves manually editing javascript code resulting from compilation. This is not desirable since a compiler should produce code that hasn´t to be edited manually after compilation (abstraction).
And it is not clear to me if google closure compiler can cope with the ceylon flavour of it in a reliable way.

Is it instead a solution to copy ceylon.language source in ceylon into the project and import only those parts of ceylon.language into the project that are required by it? Then compile to javascript. And then leave away ceylon.language-1.2.0.js at all from the client / in-browser application.

Now my questions:

1. What parts are needed in the most simple browser application? I think of something like Array(String) and the like.
2. Has that solution a chance to work absolutely reliable?
3. Will there be a better solution coming from the authors of ceylon that make this attempt obsolete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation of the language module to JS is a tricky process, because of the native stuff involved and because there are a couple of declarations that have to be in a certain order for things to work.

Minification is still pending, we are going to do it but it's not the highest priority right now, and we have to determine the best way to solve this problem; one option that has been discussed is to have a version of the language module without any metamodel info, for example.